# Eclipse call hierarchy for CDT not fully working

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, call-hierarchy

The eclipse call hierarchy for CDT is not showing all function calls for some of my functions. All of my source is within the project folder. I tried adding the locations to project->properties->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols and rebuilt the index but it did not work. For example, one function is getting called a couple of times from some library code. It's not a virtual function or anything and using ctrl-click works. The project compiles fine too.

If anything, can someone tell me where to look to troubleshoot this?  Maybe I did not create the project correctly and it does not know that all of the files are apart of the same project. I know there are several ways to import/create a C++ project and maybe I didn't do it correctly. Or maybe I need to delete some intellisense file to get the indexer to rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

I had some equivalent issue in the past with old versions of Eclipse. I think it probably resolved itself when I updated it (I have been stuck with Indigo quite a time, I think Juno or Luna made it better for me). Sorry for the obvious answer but if not done yet, try latest versions.